# How to get only last records grouped by some value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have model Message (id, text, sender_id, recipient_id, created_at).
I need to get only last records in scope of each recipient_id. It's like in most messangers page with all conversations.

For example, I have this (recipient is current_user):

```
id, sender_id, created_at
1, 1, 10.04.15
2, 1, 11.04.15
3, 2, 12.04.15
4, 3, 13.04.15
5, 2, 14.04.15
```

With query I need to get only values with ids 2, 4, 5, grouped by :

```
id, sender_id, created_at
2, 1, 11.04.15
4, 3, 13.04.15
5, 2, 14.04.15
```

With this select we have all the records, grouped by user:

```
Message.order(created_at: :desc).group_by(:sender_id)
```

Comment: show ur expected output and the select that u already tried

Comment: You just need the last messages, or the last message of each sender? (for a certain recipient)

Comment: @nathanvda, yes, of each sender :)

Answer (score 8):

You can break down the following on each step to see what the output is:

```
latest_ids = Message.group(:recipient_id).maximum(:id).values
```

With the IDs obtained, you might want to fetch the records:

```
Message.where(id: latest_ids)
```

Two queries, yes, but this is cleaner than the alternative which might involve writing some SQL yourself.

Comment: I've made some updates in post. Thanks for the way, I'll try it and let know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following select query to get the desired out via PostgreSQL

```
SELECT id
    ,created_at
    ,recipient_id
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,created_at
        ,recipient_id
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY recipient_id ORDER BY created_at DESC
            ) rn
    FROM dt
    ) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want, for a given `current_user` the last message per user that has sent a message to the `current_user`. This is imho best tackled in two stages: fetch the ids of the messages, and then fetch the messages themselves.

So you could write:

```
last_msg_ids = current_user.messages.group(:sender_id).maximum(:id)
```

assuming the association `messages` for a user is defined, if not add

```
has_many :messages, foreign_key: :recipient_id
has_many :sent_messages, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'Message'
```

or alternatively you could write (without the associations)

```
last_msg_ids= Message.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).group(:sender_id).maximum(:id)
```

and then fetch all the messages with those ids:

```
@messages = Message.where(id: last_msg_ids)
```